# Spring-Data-Gemfire Unexpected "The cache is closed."

Tags: java, spring, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

Using gemfire 8.1 and spring-gemfire-data, version 1.5.2.RELEASE.

I get some isolated errors of "com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.CacheClosedException: The cache is closed."

Which can be the cause? As I am not manually doing anything...and let spring data do the job...

```
com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.CacheClosedException: The cache is closed.
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.GemFireCacheImpl$Stopper.generateCancelledException(GemFireCacheImpl.java:1294)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.CancelCriterion.checkCancelInProgress(CancelCriterion.java:82)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.TXManagerImpl.checkClosed(TXManagerImpl.java:606)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.TXManagerImpl.begin(TXManagerImpl.java:279)
        at org.springframework.data.gemfire.GemfireTransactionManager.doBegin(GemfireTransactionManager.java:125)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:420)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:257)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
```

Comment: can you post the spring configuration and logs with the full stacktrace?

Comment: added the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Seems your Stack Trace is incomplete, not revealing everything (i.e. missing "Caused By:").  Please include the entire Stack Trace.

It is difficult to determine if this is coming from within your application, or perhaps a test case.  It is not likely that GemFire would "close" due to a TransactionException. So, including some configuration and the code directly involved would be helpful.  Even better, a test reliably reproducing the issue is extremely helpful and preferred as that is always my first step in resolving all issues.

It is also worth noting Spring Data GemFire 1.5.x is based on GemFire 7.0.2 (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/v1.5.2.RELEASE/gradle.properties#L4) and not necessarily appropriate for GemFire 8.1, although, it has been known to work in the majority of the UCs (Gateways is one exception, however).

Technically, the upcoming Spring Data GemFire 1.7.0 release (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/master/gradle.properties#L3) has full support and is compatible with GemFire 8.1, although has not reached final GA yet (currently at 1.7.0 M1).  The latest release with GemFire 8.0 support is Spring Data GemFire 1.6.2.RELEASE

See the Spring Data GemFire home page for more details on current releases (http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/) and the Spring Data Wiki, "Release planning" page for release schedule (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-planning).  Note, the current, active releases, Fowler (SDG 1.6.x) and Gosling (1.7.x) are hyperlinked.

Thanks